# Abp Framework - How do you debug code? exceptions are not caught but are logged

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I'm experiencing an issue where a very short code block within a try/catch block is not catching exceptions. For example, if I try to insert a null value into a non-nullable field in the database, the exception is being logged in the host project's log file, but I cannot catch it while debugging. Do you have any ideas why this might be happening? Here is the code:

```
  public override async Task<ReportDTO> CreateAsync(CreateReportDTO input)
        {
            try
            {
                input.UserId = (Guid)CurrentUser.Id;
                var report = await base.CreateAsync(input);
                return report;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown before the CreateAsync is called via the AbpValidationActionFilter.

---

if you want to bypass the validation you could use [DisableValidation] attribute.

for more information you could read https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Validation#validation-infrastructure

Comment: That still doesn't help me catch the exception, seems to do nothing, tried putting it on the class/method